# Whole domain 301 redirect with changing url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've merged two websites (moved posts from old website to new one).
And I want to make permanent redirect to new website. 
The problem is old website posts had this structure: "http://oldsite.com/page/", but new site posts looks like this: "http://newsite.com/page.html".

So I've wrote in .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/$ http://newsite.com$1.html
```

And it's ok with particular posts, but when you try to reach root of `http://oldsite.com/` you got redirect to `http://newsite.com.html/`

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem using 2 redirect rules, works for me now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/ [L,R=301]

# for all other pages
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/$ http://newsite$1.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break this into 2 redirect rules:

```
# for pages
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^.]*[^/])$ http://newsite.com/$1.html

# for landing and other page
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/$ http://newsite.com$1/
```

Comment: Make sure these rules are first 2 rules in your .htaccess and you test in a new browser.

Comment: 2 rules provided by you works good for root of website, but when I try to go any oldsite post I got this redirect:
`http://newsite.com/page/.html`

Comment: ok check my updated answer now. And please don't post your attempts as an answer (just edit your question with your code).